# How to rewrite the post slug of a custom post type post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want to have this URL structure for my custom post type *word*:

`host.com/words/{the-word}-meaning`

I have tried using rewrite from custom Postype with no luck so now I'm trying with this method:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^words/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+)-meaning)?/?$', 'index.php?word=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

but it is passing the whole word along with -meaning through the word postype parameter. for example

- index.php?word=run-meaning  (wrong).
- **i want to get this** index.php?word=run  (right)

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are accidentally including `-meaning` inside your second match string.  Instead of this:

`^words/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+)-meaning)?/?$`

... try this:

`^words/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))-meaning?/?$`

And don't forget to flush your permalinks after a change to the rules!